# How do I correct this script

Tags: sql

I want to be able to produce results that
If there is a commission it produces it
If there is not a commission it produces the manager_id
If there is no manager_id or commission it produces -1

I'm thinking I might have to do `NLV2(NVL2(NVL2)))` but I am unsure. This is the code I produced I'm sureI'm wrong.

```
SELECT first,
       last_name, 
       CASE commission_pct
            WHEN commission_pct IS NOT NULL THEN commision_pct
            WHEN commission_pct IS NULL THEN manager_id
            WHEN commission_pct AND manager_id IS NULL THEN -1
       END AS "Which Function???"
FROM employees
```

Comment: What insane logic is your application using to determine if the investigation of "commission_pct" is a manager ID, or a commission percentage?  My advice here is to return *both*.

Comment: @Mo920192: Yes, this query is incorrect. You return `manager_id` whenever `commission_pct` is null, no matter whether  `manager_id` is null or not. It would have to be `... WHEN commission_pct IS NULL AND manager_id IS NOT NULL THEN manager_id ELSE -1 END`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `COALESCE` which returns the first non-null value:

```
select 
  first_name, 
  last_name, 
  coalesce(commission_pct, manager_id, -1)
from employees;
```